# Suggested TCP socket settings for low latency and small packets

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm wondering if there are tweaks I can do to a TCP socket, except disabling Nagle, in order to get the lowest possible latency for a client-server protocol with predominantly small packets.

Client packet are mostly smaller than 100 bytes, server packets 100-300 bytes in size.

I'm using java on the server end and (objective-) c on the client side.

Comment: If its a simple request-response protocol, you could consider using UDP.

Comment: @stark I know, but I want to measure with the best possible TCP settings to compare.

Comment: I doubt it. Disabling Nagle should be enough, unless you want to tweak some timers, which isn't advisable IMO.

Comment: @EJP what tweaking could be done?

Comment: As it isn't advisable I decline to advise, sorry. I suggest you implement with no Nagle and then see whether you still have a problem.

Comment: @EJP oh, I definitely still see issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider reducing delayed ack timeout (if possible). Even though Nagle is turned off, in a situation where you send packets infrequently and packet loss has occurred, delayed ack could cause delay in packet loss detection then retransmission delay.

Comment: At what level is that possible? I don't remember seeing that setting exposed in the implementations I've checked.

Comment: It's described in man tcp(7): http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp  There is a TCP socket option called TCP_QUICKACK) on linux, which is not portable and may not available on your platform (or supported in a different way - not sure), however, I just thought worth mentioning it here.